# Find/Replace regex to remove html tags

Tags: regex, notepad++

Using find and replace, what regex would remove the tags surrounding something like this:

`<option value="863">Viticulture and Enology</option>`

Note: the option value changes to different numbers, **but using a regular expression to remove numbers is acceptable**

I am still trying to learn but I can't get it to work.

**I'm not using it to parse HTML, I have data from one of our company websites that we need in excel, but our designer deleted the original data file and we need it back. I have a list of the options and need to remove the HTML tags, using Notepad++ to find and replace**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This works for me Notepad++ 5.8.6 (UNICODE)

search : `<option value="\d+">(.*?)</option>`

replace : `$1`

Be sure to select "Regular expression" and ". matches newline"
[image]

Answer (score 12):

I have done by using following regular expression:

**Find this :** `<.*?>|</.*?>`

and

**replace with :** `\r\n` (this for new line)

By using this regular expression (`<.*?>|</.*?>`) we can easily find value between your `HTML` tags like below:

[image]

I have input:

```
<otpion value="123">1</option><otpion value="1234">2</option><otpion value="1235">3</option><otpion value="1236">4</option><otpion value="1237">5</option>
```

I need to find values between options like 1,2,3,4,5

[image]

and got below output :

[image]

Answer (score 8):

This works perfectly for me:

- Select "Regular Expression" in "Find" Mode.
- Enter [<].*?> in "Find What" field and leave the "Replace With" field empty.
- Note that you need to have version 5.9 of Notepad++ for the ? operator to work.

as found here:
[digoCOdigo - strip html tags in notepad++](http://www.digocodigo.com/2012/03/code-to-strip-html-tags-in-notepad-and.html)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this would work (as long as you know the format of the HTML won't change):

```
<option value="(\d+)">(.+)</option>
```

Comment: Hm, this erased the entire line, but looks close.

Comment: I will do two find and replaces: one for <option value="(\d+)"> and then one for </option>. Works beautifully thank you.

Comment: If you're using Notepad++ find/replace, it's not going to work because the regex uses backreferences to capture the fields you want to keep.  For find/replace, just replace everything before the numbers with nothing, then replace `">` with a delimeter (like | but not commas, since there may be commas in the name), then finall replace the </option> with nothing.  Import the result into Excel.

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "<option value=\"863\">Viticulture and Enology</option>";
s.replaceAll ("(<option value=\"[0-9]+\">)([^<]+)</option>", "$2")
res1: java.lang.String = Viticulture and Enology
```

(Tested with scala, therefore the res1:)

With sed, you would use a little different syntax:

```
echo '<option value="863">Viticulture and Enology</option>'|sed -re 's|(<option value="[0-9]+">)([^<]+)</option>|\2|'
```

For notepad++, I don't know the details, but "[0-9]+" should mean 'at least one digit', "[^<]" anything but a opening less-than, multiple times. Masking and backreferences may differ.
Regexes are problematic, if they span multiple lines, or are hidden by a comment, a regex will not recognize it.

However, a lot of html is genereated in a regex-friendly way, always fitting into a line, and never commented out. Or you use it in throwaway code, and can check your input before.

Comment: this is really helpful, just gonna loop through them all now :D TY!