# Regex Capture betwee 2 Strings/Value

Tags: html, regex, notepad++

i want to capture a value between 2 strings, i tried many regex but no way.

Source Code:

```
</li><li><a href="/Journal/Year/123">Journal Title 2002</a> | <a href="/Journal/Year/456">2004</a> | <a href="/Journal/Year/789">2005</a></ul></div>
```

Regex i Tried:

```
(<li><a href=".journal.year.\d+">)(.*)(<a href=".journal.year.\d+">)
(?<=<li><a href=".journal.year.\d+">)(.*)(?=<a href=".journal.year.\d+">)
```

Capture Output :

```
Journal Title 2002
```

or  (if possible)

```
Journal Title 2002 2004 2005
```

i hope you will help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The downvotes are probably happening because you are trying to parse HTML content using regex.  While regex might be part of the solution, you should consider using an HTML/XML parser.

Comment: Try [removing all tags](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39422916/3832970).

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to use a RegEx to parse HTML.

Instead use DOM

```js
var titles = [];
document.querySelectorAll("[href^='/Journal']").forEach(function(link) {
  titles.push(link.textContent.trim())
});
console.log(titles.join(" "));
```

```html
<ul><li><a href="/Journal/Year/123">Journal Title 2002</a> | <a href="/Journal/Year/456">2004</a> | <a href="/Journal/Year/789">2005</a></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i am using a program and parsing is only available sing LR strings, Json, Regex and CSS Selector

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/IVUmJf/1

```
\>([^<|]+)\<
```

This Regex should work for your purpose. It captures everything between `>` and `<` except if there is a `|`.